# Binding to a depencency property doesn't work

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, dependency-properties

I derived ImageButton from Button class.  I want to be able to set text on it using custom property.

ImageButton XAML

```
<Button x:Class="MyProject.ImageButton"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Height="50" Width="75" Template="{DynamicResource BlueButton}">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path = ImageButton.ButtonText}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Foreground="White"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Button>
```

ImageButton code behind

```
    public partial class ImageButton : Button
    { 
        public string ButtonText
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(ButtonTextProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ButtonTextProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty ButtonTextProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("ButtonText", typeof(string), typeof(ImageButton), new UIPropertyMetadata(string.Empty));

        public ImageButton()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
```

Client code:

```
<local:ImageButton Margin="114,15.879,96,15.878" Grid.Row="2" ButtonText="test"/>
```

No text is being shown on the button.  For some reason the binding doesn't seem to be taking place.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How are you binding to the button?

Comment: Shouldn't the TextBlock binding be just "ButtonText"? If you're within the ImageButton, you should just have to bind to the property name.

Comment: Look at the 'Client code:' at the very button.  I set ButtonText property to "test".

Comment: I tried the following variations and none of them works: "Binding ButtonText", "Binding Path = ButtonText", "Binding Path = ImageButton.ButtonText".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don’t have a `DataContext` set, so the data binding doesn’t know which source object it should bind to.

I find that the easiest way to resolve this is to give your outer control a name, and reference it using `ElementName` in your binding:

```
<Button x:Class="MyProject.ImageButton"
        x:Name="myImageButton"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Height="50" Width="75" Template="{DynamicResource BlueButton}">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=myImageButton, Path=ButtonText}" 
                   TextWrapping="Wrap" Foreground="White"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Button>
```

Comment: @Eternal21: Glad to help! For the record, you can set `DataContext` from the code-behind instead and avoid naming your `ImageButton`, but I personally prefer the above approach.

Comment: How would I set datacontext inside code-behind?  Just DataContext = this?

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
 <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path = ImageButton.ButtonText}"
```

to

```
   <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path = ButtonText}"
```